# How to make a token with modifiable price and supply?

Tags: solidity, payable

I need to create an erc20 token with the function "payable" thats means that when you send some ether to the token contract (like 1 Token = 0.5 ETH) send the amount of tokens to the wallet that sent the ether, see an example here:

https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-build-your-own-ethereum-based-erc20-token-and-launch-an-ico-in-next-20-minutes-cjbcpwzec01c93awtbij90uzn)

But I need the permition to change the price whenever I want, and change the supply (burn and add tokens) too.

some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your contract code to better help you, but in general what you can do is create a state variable that represents the price of your token in wei and then create a setter function that changes that value.

```
uint public price;

function setPrice(uint newPrice) public {
    require(newPrice > 0);
    price = newPrice;
}
```

The same can be said for adding and subtracting your total supply of tokens.

```
uint public totalSupply = 100000;

function addTokenToTotalSupply(uint _value) public {
    require(_value > 0);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender] + _value;
    totalSupply = totalSupply + _value;
}
```